# Find the solutions of $\cosh(z)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the solutions of $\cosh(z)=1$

**My attempt:**

Note $\cosh(z)=\cos(y)\cosh(x)+i\sin(y)\sinh(x)=1\iff \cos(y)\cosh(x)=1 \quad\text{and} \quad\sin(y)\sinh(x)=0$

Suppose $x=0$ then $\cos(y)=1\implies y=\pi+2k\pi$

Then $z=i(\pi+2k\pi)$

Is correct this?

Comment: $\cos(y)=1\implies y=2k\pi$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\cos y=1,y=2n\pi$

Alternatively

$2\cosh(z)=e^z+e^{-z}$

So, we have $e^z=1\implies z=2n\pi i$ where $n$ is an integer

Answer (score 1):

Two cases to consider:

1) $\sinh x =0 $ yields $x=0$ and $y=2\pi k$.

2) $\sin y = 0$ yields $y=\pi k$ and $\cos y = \pm 1$. However, only $\cos y = 1$, or $y=2\pi k $, is valid due to $\cos y \cosh x =1$.

Thus, the solution is $z=2\pi k i $.